# FindControl on control in invisible Panel generates Null reference error

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

The following code produces a null reference error on this line `href.NavigateUrl = "foo.aspx?id=" + id;` when I change the DropDownList selection, but not when I enter the id as a QueryString parameter. It seems like it has something to do with the order of events, but I'm not sure what, or how to fix it.

**.aspx**

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
        <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
</asp:Panel>
<br />
<asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
                <RoleGroups>
                    <asp:RoleGroup Roles="superadmin">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="HyperLink1">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:RoleGroup>
                </RoleGroups>
    </asp:LoginView>
</asp:Panel>
```

**.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["id"]))
        {
            Panel1.Visible = false;
            SetHref(Request.QueryString["id"]);
        }
    }
}

protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetHref(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
}

protected void SetHref(string id)
{
    Panel2.Visible = true;
    HyperLink href = (HyperLink)LoginView1.FindControl("HyperLink1");
    href.NavigateUrl = "foo.aspx?id=" + id;
    href.Text = href.NavigateUrl;
}
```

I've found a couple of work-arounds: setting the default visbility of Panel2 to true is one, and moving the HyperLink outside of Panel2 and changing its visibility directly is the other, but neither of those do exactly what I want because there are other controls that I am trying make visible/invisible along with the HyperLink.

Any thoughts?

Comment: HyperLink href = (HyperLink)LoginView1.FindControl("HyperLink1"); your this line is getting problem,,he is not getting hyperlink control,,

Comment: I agree. Can you offer any advice on how to properly locate it?

Comment: instead of Visible property try for Style display:None;

Comment: See my comment on Abe Miessler's answer below. In short: it's not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the following line:

```
Panel2.Visible = true;
```

Try using:

```
Panel2.Attributes["style"] = "display:none";
```

I think the contents of your panel might not be rendering when you set `Visible` to `false`.

Comment: If I do that, the HTML contents of the Panel will be delivered to the browser, but the resulting DIV will just be made not visible through CSS, right? That's not ideal in this case. It would be better for me to change the layout of the page to allow for the HyperLink to be outside of the Panel. It seems to me that there should be a way to do what I am after...

Comment: Why is it not ideal and why do you think it would be better to change the layout?

Comment: I have other controls that are included in that panel besides the HyperLink - GridView, CheckBoxList, etc, all of which are being DataBound to queries based on the id that is being supplied in the code provided above. I don't want to process and deliver a bunch of useless code to the browser just to make it invisible via CSS. At this point I think I am just going to move the HyperLink outside of the Panel, and set the HyperLink's visibility directly.